# Is there a way in flutter to provide the Type for Consumer<T> from parameter?

Tags: flutter, refactoring, flutter-provider

My problem in summary: I have an app, that has 3-4 master data lists which are stored in SQLite. These list are identical so I could reuse most of the widgets that build up the different master data screens. The problem is that the data is coming from different providers and I cannot find the way to extract these widgets.

This is the part where I construct the list of FishTypes using the Consumer. Can I reuse this somehow for DogTypes, CatTypes etc. without copying the whole code?

```
Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _items,
              builder: (ctx, snapshot) =>
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                      ? Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        )
                      : Consumer<FishTypes>(
                          builder: (ctx, fishType, _) => ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: fishType.items.length,
                            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) =>
                                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                              value: fishType.items[i],
                              child: MasterDataMenuItem(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The MasterDataMenuItem widget is basically a ListTile, where I also use Consumer to rebuild the widget when Favorite or Active switch is toggled. This is again a widget that I'd like to reuse with other Consumer types.

```
  class MasterDataMenuItem extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 5),
      child: Consumer<FishType>(
        builder: (_, fishType, __) => ListTile(
          tileColor: Colors.black54,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(fishType.isFavorite ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border),
            onPressed: () {
              fishType.toggleFavorite();
            },
          ),
          title: Text(
            fishType.name,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: fishType.isUsed
              ? Switch(
                  value: fishType.isActive,
                  onChanged: (_) {
                    fishType.toggleActive();
                  },
                )
              : IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Provider.of<FishTypes>(context, listen: false)
                        .deleteFishType(fishType.id!);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible without copy / paste -ing the whole code and only change the Consumer types?

Note: there are some other parts on the screens such as title, and a text input field, but these are the parts that cause me most of the headache so I copied here only these parts.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Hi! How similar your models are (FishType, DogType etc.)? Do they use the same UI or items looks different?

Comment: Hi! They are completely identical. They have the sam fields (eg. name, isFavorite) and same functions in the provider. In the meantime I've found a workaround. Created a getData method that runs when the Widget is built. In this method I use a switch statement that decides what type of data is displayed and passes the appropriate data to the widget. Since the providers have similar methods (eg. _toggleFavorite) now it is working fine.